# How can I sort records by average rating with latsrate gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using letsrate gem for rating https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate
How can i sort my records by average rating? 
Or do i have to write from scratch my own rating?

Comment: In case you're looking for more options, there are a few more [gems that help with rating / voting / liking](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/activerecord-rating-liking-voting-ruby). However, in your case, you might try to take a look at the [class method the letsrate_rateable call](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate/blob/master/lib/letsrate/model.rb#L75-93) adds to your model and try a few things.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is ridiculous that rating value cant be accessed

Comment: You could open as issue on Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to sort by rating with the Letsrate gem, but because of a bug, it is a little difficult. Take for example, an app with `User`s who rate `Car`s on speed, engine, and price.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  letsrate_rateable "speed", "engine", "price"
end
```

Now, you can create some users, cars, and ratings.

```
user = User.create!(email: 'user@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
other = User.create!(email: 'other@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')

camry = Car.create!(name: 'Camry')
mustang = Car.create!(name: 'Mustang')
ferrari = Car.create!(name: 'Ferrari')

camry.rate 2, user.id, 'speed'
camry.rate 3, user.id, 'engine'
camry.rate 5, user.id, 'price'
camry.rate 4, user.id
mustang.rate 3, user.id, 'speed'
mustang.rate 4, user.id, 'engine'
mustang.rate 3, user.id, 'price'
mustang.rate 3, user.id
ferrari.rate 5, user.id, 'speed'
ferrari.rate 5, user.id, 'engine'
ferrari.rate 1, user.id, 'price'
ferrari.rate 5, user.id

camry.rate 3, other.id, 'speed'
camry.rate 2, other.id, 'engine'
camry.rate 4, other.id, 'price'
camry.rate 5, other.id
mustang.rate 4, other.id, 'speed'
mustang.rate 3, other.id, 'engine'
mustang.rate 3, other.id, 'price'
mustang.rate 4, other.id
ferrari.rate 5, other.id, 'speed'
ferrari.rate 4, other.id, 'engine'
ferrari.rate 1, other.id, 'price'
ferrari.rate 4, other.id
```

It is easy to sort based on the overall rating, with no dimension, by joining with the `rate_average_without_dimension` association:

```
Car.joins(:rate_average_without_dimension).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
```

You could scope this out as

```
scope :sorted_by_rating_without_dimension, joins(:rate_average_without_dimension).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
scope :top_ten_without_dimension, sorted_by_rating_without_dimension.limit(10)
```

And now you can include a 'Top 10' list:

```
Car.top_ten_without_dimension
```

However, what if you want a 'Top 10 Engines' or 'Best Value' list? It should be as simple as

```
Car.joins(:engine_average).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
Car.joins(:price_average).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
```

But, you'll get an error

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'engine_average' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it
```

This is because Letsrate creates its associations with strings instead of symbols. As a workaround, you can change your `letsrate_rateable` call to the following:

```
DIMENSIONS = ["speed", "engine", "price"]
letsrate_rateable *DIMENSIONS

DIMENSIONS.each do |dimension|
  has_one :"#{dimension}_average", :as => :cacheable, :class_name => "RatingCache", :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}
end
```

(note the `:` in front of the `"#{dimension}_average"` interpolation).

Now, you can use

```
Car.joins(:engine_average).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
```

Or as scopes,

```
scope :sorted_by_engine_rating, joins(:engine_average).order('rating_caches.avg DESC')
scope :top_ten_engines, sorted_by_engine_rating.limit(10)
```

I have [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate/pull/28) that fixes this bug. Feel free to comment or give it a +1 to get it accepted.

Comment: **Benjamin** thank you very much for you help! Now it doesn't show records who has no rating value and sorted_by_engine_rating.limit(10) raises undefined local variable or method `sorted_by_rating_without_dimension'.

Comment: No problem! If you're running an older version of Rails, you might need to use a lambda for the nested scopes. `scope :sorted_by_engine_rating, lambda { joins(:engine_average).order('rating_caches.avg DESC') }; scope :top_ten_engines, lambda { sorted_by_engine_rating.limit(10) }`

Comment: To include cars without ratings, use `includes(:engine_average)` instead of `joins(:engine_average)`.